# Setting up Ruby along with android in docker

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, dockerfile

I have an issue while setting up docker container with android and ruby environment to run calabash test. I have [this](https://github.com/tracer0tong/android-emulator) docker file for the android part. Whenever I am editing the docker file to install the latest version of ruby and for calabash just like below code

```
RUN gem install calabash-android
```

I am getting error just like

> /bin/sh: 1: gem: not found
>   The command '/bin/sh -c gem install calabash-android' returned a non-zero code: 127

And after that I have tried

```
FROM tracer0tong/android-emulator

FROM ruby:2.3.0

RUN gem install calabash-android
```

like syntax to check whether it is gonna work and seems like not. Is there any way to install both?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting an error is that the Android Docker image you're using does not have Ruby installed (rightly so).
And [this Github issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/13026) expains why multiple `FROM` directives in one Dockerfile is not a good idea.
IMO your best bet would be to see how Ruby is installed in the Ruby Docker image and copy that over into your Dockerfile that builds off of the Android image. Or vice versa - whichever is less effort.

Comment: Thanks @Evgeny Chernyavskiy, I have tried the dockerfiles in the docker hub. But it was raising errors such as "E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
" for every docker files. I have tried almost all files.